# Can I access paths defined in svg file imported via canvg?

Tags: canvas, svg, path, click, canvg

I have an image in an svg file that I imported into a <canvas> object using canvg (http://code.google.com/p/canvg/).

```
canvg('canvas', '../path/to/your.svg')
```

I need to perform an action whenever the user clicks inside one of the paths defined in the svg file. Is that possible?

Canvas is not needed, if this can be done without it please let me know (Is there something like ?)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can try this with Kinetic.js . Please take a look at the [HTML5 Canvas World Map SVG Path with KineticJS example](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-world-map-svg-path-with-kineticjs/).